# Regular expression syntax advice needed

Tags: regex, sed

Could someone please advise me what I may be doing wrong here:

```
sed 's/&.*?;\s//'
```

I'm trying to delete all but 'THIS TEXT'

```
lt;td rowspan="2" width="80" valign="top" &gt;&#xD;
&lt;img src="http://foo.bar/image.jpeg" /&gt;&#xD;
&lt;/td&gt;&#xD;
&lt;td&gt;&#xD;
THIS TEXT&#xD;
&#xD;
```

Comment: Trying to replace what with what?

Comment: given the empty replacement target, i.e. `//`, you might want to edit your question to rephrase it as "delete everything but 'THIS TEXT'". Do you expect to have 1 remaining line, or 4 blank lines, 'THIS TEXT' and another blank line? Good luck.

Comment: thanks, I edited the question. im trying to delete all but 'THIS TEXT' with no blank lines

Answer (score 0):

If the string your searching for is constant, you could just use a simple `grep`:

```
grep -o "THIS TEXT" file.txt
```

Else, you could use `sed` and some pattern matching, try:

```
sed -e 's/&.*;$//' -e '/^$/d' -e '/^lt;td/d' file.txt
```

You may need to include multiple expressions like: `-e '/^lt;td/d'` to remove other undesirable lines in your data file, if it contains them.

HTH

Comment: sed example is exactly what I need, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression `&.*?;\s` searches:

- One apersand `&`
- Arbitrarily many arbitrary characters `.*`
- **A question mark `?`**
- One semicolon `;`
- **One whitespace character `\s`**

But there is no question mark and no whitespace after `;` in your sample text.

Note that `?` is not interpreted as a repetition operator per default. If you want that, you need to enable "extended" regular expressions using `sed -r` (or `sed -E` on Mac). This is a backwards compatibility thing.

Comment: thank you for your answer it helps me further understand what i'm trying to acheive

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this?

```
bash:/home/tene>cat file
lt;td rowspan="2" width="80" valign="top" &gt;&#xD;
&lt;img src="http://foo.bar/image.jpeg" /&gt;&#xD;
&lt;/td&gt;&#xD;
&lt;td&gt;&#xD;
THIS TEXT&#xD;
&#xD;

bash:/home/tene>sed -e '/^[&l]/d' -e 's/&#xD;$//g' file
THIS TEXT
```